# After trying to install Brave Browser I can't update de system anymore

Tags: updates

Hello I have this problem, I don't know how to solve it?

[image]

Comment: Can you post the result of command `ls -al /etc/apt/sources.list.d`
Probably there is also a misconfiguration in your file.
You should be able to update the system when temporarily move the file to another place.
Can you provide the content of this file? What release do you use (Juno or Hera)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the source list file for the brave browser is corrupted. You can remove it with

`sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release-.list`

and try to install it again later.

Comment: This command solve the problem. Thank you.